# PayPal Express set up in Store

Tags: expresso-store, paypal-express-checkout

I am trying to get my info to set up PayPal express with Store.

When I login to my PayPal account I am not seeing what they are asking:

From Store Docs:

PayPal Express Checkout requires an API Username, Password, and Signature. These are different from your PayPal account details. You can obtain your API details by logging in to your PayPal account, and clicking Profile > My Selling Tools > API Access > Request/View API Credentials > Request API Signature.

When I click Profile I do not see My selling tools.

I do find on my profiel page: Request API credentials, but when I click that I see:
Setting up API permissions and credentials
Choose one of the following options to integrate your PayPal payment solution with your online store or shopping cart.

Grant API permission

Then I see:
Add New Third Party Permissions
Manage permission given to a third-party application to access specific information in your account and take actions on your behalf.

For more information about the permissions you are granting, see Third Party Permissions.

Third Party Permission Username

If I click View API Certificate
I get 
API Username    name_api1.gmail.com

API Password    ••••••••••••

Request Date

but no signature??????

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what my PayPal profile page looks like, not sure why you can't see *My Selling Tools*:

[image]

It sounds like you have set up an *API Certificate* rather than a signature (probably for a different shopping cart). You probably need to go into the *View API Certificate*, then click *Remove*.

After that, you should be able to request a new *API Signature* instead. It sounds like you can't have both a signature and certificate set up at once. I don't want to remove my signature to find out for sure though!

Comment: I removed the existing certificate, now when I try and generate a new one I get this error:Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
Cookie
/n

Comment: used another browser and was finally able to generate

Comment: Oh yeah, that is a paypal bug, happens to me every now and then too (I think from being logged into PayPal developer site as well as live site at the same time). Clearing your cookies fixes it.